# How to shift arc center in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have one circle and 4 arcs located around that circle.
Currently I'm drawing arcs like this:

```
fileprivate func addArc(from startAngle: CGFloat, to endAngle: CGFloat, of color: SKColor, with text: String) {
    let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 100, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)
    arc.flatness = 100

    let node = SKShapeNode()
    node.lineWidth = 36
    node.strokeColor = color
    node.path = arc.cgPath

    addChild(node)
}
```

and when I later try to add a new LabelNode into my arc,

```
let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: text)
labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center

node.addChild(labelNode)
```

that NodeLabel being added into the middle of the circle but not into the middle of the arcs.
I've found that the mistake is in this line:

```
let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 100, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)
```

where I'm setting `arcCenter`.
So the question is, how can I shift the center of those arcs so labelNodes will be added into arcs but not into the circle?

Comment: It's a geometry problem. labelNode.position = CGPoint(x: radius * cos(Double.pi / 4) + offset.x , y: sin(Double.pi/ 4) + offset.y ).  in this formula, radius = 100,  offset= CGPoint. Which depends on the result.

Comment: @E.Comsyou mean `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` by `offset` or?

Comment: Offset is added arbitrary after testing. You use the offset to adjust the textLabel  exact position where you need.  You can set to CGPoint.Zero as the starting point. The above formula is just for one arc. You may change the sign(+/-) of cos and sin to get other ARC. CGPoint(x: radius * (+/-)cos(Double.pi / 4) + offset.x , y: radius * (+/-)sin(Double.pi/ 4) + offset.y ).

Comment: @E.Coms it did not help to my labels =/ they are still outside of it

Comment: Post a pictures